# react-router-dom i can't printing the default value from the form to another page

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-router-dom, default-value, react-dom

I want to print the information I get from the form on the info page when I press the send button. However, when the information is taken as default value, it does not come to the info page.

Information from the form needs to be printed on the Info page

My App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './App.css';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import Info from './Info';
import Form from './Form';

function App() {

  const [form, setForm] = useState({ name: "", city: "", birth: "", color: "", address: "" });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setForm({ ...form, [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Enter your informations</h2>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" exact element={<Form form={form} onChange={handleChange}/>}></Route>
        <Route path="/info" element={<Info form={form}/>}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My Form.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

function Form({ form, HandleChange }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="isim" defaultValue={form.name} onChange={HandleChange} placeholder="Enter your name" />
                <select name="city" defaultValue={form.city} onChange={HandleChange}>
                    <option defaultValue="">Enter your city</option>
                    <option defaultValue="Ankara">Ankara</option>
                    <option defaultValue="İstanbul">İstanbul</option>
                    <option defaultValue="İzmir">İzmir</option>
                </select>
                <input type="date" name="birth" defaultValue={form.birth} onChange={HandleChange}  />
                <input type="color" name="color" defaultValue={form.color} onChange={HandleChange} />
                <textarea name="address" placeholder="Enter your address" cols="20" rows="5" defaultValue={form.adsress} onChange={HandleChange}></textarea>
                <Link to="/info"><button>Send</button></Link>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Form
```

My Info.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link} from 'react-router-dom'

function Info({form}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Name: {form.name} </p>
      <p>City: {form.city}</p>
      <p>Birthday: {form.birth}</p>
      <p>Color: {form.color}</p>
      <p>Address: {form.address}</p>
      <Link to="/"><button>Back</button></Link>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Info
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue is that the `Form` component is passed an `onChange` prop but is destructuring a `HandleChange` prop.

```
<Route
  path="/"
  element={<Form form={form} HandleChange={handleChange} />}
/>
```

Fix this to pass a consistently named prop.

```
<Route
  path="/"
  element={<Form form={form} onChange={handleChange} />}
/>
```

The second issue from what I can see of the code it seems the `button` element is submitting the form and since the default form action is not prevented the page/app is reloading. HTML `button` elements have `type="submit"` by default if not specified.

Make sure that the `name` attribute for the "name" field matches the React state key. In other words, ensure it is `name="name"` instead of `name="isim"`.

Additionally, all these form fields should *technically* be ***controlled*** inputs since you are attaching an `onChange` handler to each. Controlled inputs use the `value` prop instead of the `defaultValue` prop.

You've a couple options:

1. Declare the button to ***not*** be a form submit button.

   ```
   function Form({ form, onChange }) {
     return (
       <div>
         <form>
           <input
             type="text"
             name="name"
             value={form.name}
             onChange={onChange}
             placeholder="Enter your name"
           />
           <select name="city" value={form.city} onChange={onChange}>
             <option disabled value="">Enter your city</option>
             <option value="Ankara">Ankara</option>
             <option value="İstanbul">İstanbul</option>
             <option value="İzmir">İzmir</option>
           </select>
           <input
             type="date"
             name="birth"
             value={form.birth}
             onChange={onChange}
           />
           <input
             type="color"
             name="color"
             value={form.color}
             onChange={onChange}
           />
           <textarea
             name="address"
             placeholder="Enter your address"
             cols="20"
             rows="5"
             value={form.adsress}
             onChange={onChange}
           ></textarea>
           <Link to="/info">
             <button type="button">Send</button>
           </Link>
         </form>
       </div>
     );
   }
   ```
2. Declare a form submit handler and prevent the default form action and issue the imperative navigation action.

   ```
   import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

   function Form({ form, onChange }) {
     const navigate = useNavigate();

     const submitHandler = (e) => {
       e.preventDefault();
       navigate("/info");
     };

     return (
       <div>
         <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
           <input
             type="text"
             name="name"
             value={form.name}
             onChange={onChange}
             placeholder="Enter your name"
           />
           <select name="city" value={form.city} onChange={onChange}>
             <option disabled value="">Enter your city</option>
             <option value="Ankara">Ankara</option>
             <option value="İstanbul">İstanbul</option>
             <option value="İzmir">İzmir</option>
           </select>
           <input
             type="date"
             name="birth"
             value={form.birth}
             onChange={onChange}
           />
           <input
             type="color"
             name="color"
             value={form.color}
             onChange={onChange}
           />
           <textarea
             name="address"
             placeholder="Enter your address"
             cols="20"
             rows="5"
             value={form.adsress}
             onChange={onChange}
           ></textarea>
           <button type="submit">Send</button>
         </form>
       </div>
     );
   }
   ```

In either case you'll still want to be explicit about the button type for readability and maintainability reasons.

Demo

[image: Edit react-router-dom-i-cant-printing-the-default-value-from-the-form-to-another-pag]

Comment: Both options yielded no results. I still can't get the informations on the info page

Comment: @idil You had an additional prop issue with the `Form` component; passing an `onChange` prop but using a `HandleChange` callback in the component. I've updated my answer and provided a running sandbox demo.